# Search a user given number inside a list using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Code:

```
def search_number(list, number):
    count = 0
    for item in list:
        if(item == number):
            count += 1

    print("Count: {0}".format(count))


num = [1,4,2,3,4,5,10,20]
number = input("Enter num: ")

search_number(num, number)
```

If I enter a number such as 4, the expected output is 2, but this code of snippet provides output as 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input is a string, but your list have ints.
Transform the input to int:

```
number = int(input("Enter num: "))
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides @Netware's answer, also Python provides a vanilla way of counting:

```
num = [1,4,2,3,4,5,10,20]
print(num.count(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use a loop, although another way to get an object count by using `Counter()`:

```
from collections import Counter

num = [1,4,2,3,4,5,10,20]
number = input("Enter num: ") # 4

print(Counter(num)[int(number)]) # 2
```

↳ **[Online Example](https://repl.it/repls/FirebrickArtisticEntropy)**

Comment: I think without importing another dependency the following line of code is very helpful:

print(num.count(number))

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function returns a string. You are comparing a string with an int.

Try this:

`number = int(float(input(...)))`

Comment: why cast it to float before cast it to int?

Comment: If the string that you receive is a ```float```, casting it directly to ```int``` will throw an error. if you convert to float before, then you can cast the float number to an int, even though you lose precision in the process. ideally, you should add a ```try except```